# Close login window when scraping facebook groups using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to open facebook group page using selenium, but can't close the window that ask for login or signup:
[image]

I tried selenium but always return an `InvalidSelectorException` error.
This is the code I used:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service               #used to give driver path
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys                     #used for keyboard keys 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait             #used for waiting elem
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    #used for waiting elem 

options = Options()
options.add_argument('log-level=3')
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') #avoid detection #STR
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"]) #avoid detection  #STR
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging']) #avoid detection  #STR
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False) #avoid detection  #STR

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("C:/m/chromedriver.exe"), options=options)

url = "https://www.facebook.com/groups/1732060157100583/"
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='#mount_0_0_Oy > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(5) > div > div > div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div.x1uvtmcs.x4k7w5x.x1h91t0o.x1beo9mf.xaigb6o.x12ejxvf.x3igimt.xarpa2k.xedcshv.x1lytzrv.x1t2pt76.x7ja8zs.x1n2onr6.x1qrby5j.x1jfb8zj > div > div > div > div.x92rtbv.x10l6tqk.x1tk7jg1.x1vjfegm > div > i').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid long selectors - they are unstable and can be easily changed by rendering logic.

Close button can be easily located with css selector `[role=dialog] [role=button].x1qhmfi1`

You just need to wait for element presence, click on it and wait for close button to disappear.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait        
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument('log-level=3')
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') #avoid detection #STR
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"]) #avoid detection  #STR
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging']) #avoid detection  #STR
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False) #avoid detection  #STR

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = "https://www.facebook.com/groups/1732060157100583/"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

close = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[role=dialog] [role=button].x1qhmfi1')))
close.click()
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element(close))
```